# natural language processing: text corpus format for word2vec

Tags: python, c++, rest, nlp, word2vec

I found a tutorial that uses word2vec on a large Wikipedia DataSet
http://danielfrg.github.io/blog/2013/09/21/word2vec-yhat/
I would like to build a yhat rest API similar to the one he Daniel has demonstrated in his tutorial.

Today I put together some Spanish newspaper articles I wish to analyze. The web-site I retrieved my data formats its articles very regularly, so I have 1000 articles stored as strings, e.g.

```
"Otros se dan a conocer por la simpleza, como Sonya Cortés, 
quien expresó que atesora compartir en familia y gozar de salud.   
En el ambiente del reggaeton, Khriz, del dúo Ángel & Khriz, 
aprovechará para estrenar su nueva piscina ya que por su agenda 
de trabajo no ha podido darse un chapuzón todavía. Mientras, 
Daddy Yankee se tomará un descanso con la familia luego de una larga gira."
```

I am comfortable with Python and was hoping to use the python wrapper listed in the tutorial:
https://github.com/danielfrg/word2vec

How do I load my corpus into word2vec?  Right now I have an array of strings.

At the moment my corpus fits into memory.  Is word2vec still the right tool?

Answer (score 1):

If by

> Right now I have an array of strings

you mean that it is already tokenized.

```
sentences = gensim.models.word2vec.LineSentence(path_to_corpus)
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=10, size=500, window=10, sg=1, workers=4)
```

sentences has to be a list list of string i.e:

[ ['this', 'is' , 'my', 'first', 'sentence'], ['this', 'is', 'the', 'second']]

Answer (score 0):

Try http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html.

> At the moment my corpus fits into memory. Is word2vec still the right
>   tool?

Yes. Word2vec (both the C and Python version) can work with corpora larger than RAM. Smaller than RAM works too, of course.

Comment: Cool! I am trying it out, but I got stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362993/how-to-load-sentences-into-python-gensim

Comment: I know. I commented there too :)