# How to load sentences into Python gensim?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am trying to use the [`word2vec`](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) module from `gensim` natural language processing library in Python.

The docs say to initialize the model:

```python
from gensim.models import word2vec
model = Word2Vec(sentences, size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

What format does `gensim` expect for the input sentences?  I have raw text

```
"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs"
"Then a cop quizzed Mick Jagger's ex-wives briefly."
etc.
```

What additional processing do I need to post into `word2fec`?

---

**UPDATE:** Here is what I have tried.  When it loads the sentences, I get nothing.

```
>>> sentences = ['the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs',
             "Then a cop quizzed Mick Jagger's ex-wives briefly."]
>>> x = word2vec.Word2Vec()
>>> x.build_vocab([s.encode('utf-8').split( ) for s in sentences])
>>> x.vocab
{}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[A list of `utf-8` sentences](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec). You can also stream the data from the disk.

Make sure it's `utf-8`, and split it:

```
sentences = [ "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs",
"Then a cop quizzed Mick Jagger's ex-wives briefly." ]
word2vec.Word2Vec([s.encode('utf-8').split() for s in sentences], size=100, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4)
```

Comment: actually, sentence has to be a list of words, not a string, i.e. `s.encode('utf-8').split()`

Comment: Whoops sorry. Updated. Thanks

Comment: `RuntimeError: you must first build vocabulary before training the model`

Comment: Which line? Is that from my code? If it isn't, then it's a separate question.

Comment: @alKid the second line.  I imported `gensim` and ran your script verbatim. `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 162, in __init__` and `"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 244, in train`

Comment: @alkid Or if you look at my **update**, I ran `Word2Vec.build_vocab` directly but `vocab` was still empty afterwards.

Comment: Enable logging and observe what it says. Therein lies your answer. Spoiler: `min_count=5`.

Comment: @alKid good answer, but it's a sequence (an iterable) of sentences = not necessarily a list. This makes a big differences when `sentences` is larger than RAM, i.e. streamed from disk.

Comment: @Radim Thanks a lot for observing that.

Comment: @alkid can you show how to input data from disk? also what other datasets besides text8 are available?

Comment: adding utf8 encoding gives me **TypeError: can't concat bytes to string**

Answer (score 5):

Like `alKid` pointed out, make it `utf-8`.

Talking about two additional things you might have to worry about.

1. Input is too large and you're loading it from a file.
2. Removing stop words from the sentences.

Instead of loading a big list into the memory, you can do something like:

```
import nltk, gensim
class FileToSent(object):    
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        self.stop = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))

    def __iter__(self):
        for line in open(self.filename, 'r'):
           ll = [i for i in unicode(line, 'utf-8').lower().split() if i not in self.stop]
           yield ll
```

And then,

```
sentences = FileToSent('sentence_file.txt')
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=sentences, window=5, min_count=5, workers=4, hs=1)
```

Comment: Don't remove stop words. That is a decades-old practice no longer considered useful in modern NLP.